# Do I need a server to use git?

Tags: git

If I need to get access to my files on my home computer from work or whatever, do I need to have a network server and check-in the files on there?

If I'm using `git`, do I still need to have a server or am I actually saving files on their server?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague.  If you could provide your ideal workflow we may be better able to answer your question.

Comment: The answers that I got so far are exactly what I needed. unfuddle is the way to go.

Comment: If you have an old computer sitting around, absolutely nothing is stopping you from downloading an Ubuntu CD and getting a neat little server up and running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a number of hosted solutions for Git repositories, including [GitHub](http://Github.com) and [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com).

The wording of your question indicates that you might misunderstand what Git (and Distributed Version Control Systems in general) are all about. You might want to read the intro to Git at Unfuddle or an introduction to Git like the one [here](http://blog.xkoder.com/2008/08/13/git-tutorial-starting-with-git-using-just-10-commands/).

Comment: Well from what I understand so far, Git acts like sourcesafe/subversion. but I would need a centralized server to checkin code for those; So is GitHub the centralized server that I'm looking for

Comment: it can serve that purpose, definitely. GitHub does not have free private repositories, but Unfuddle does.

Answer (score 17):

First, Git is **distributed** version control system. This means that when working with Git you have full repository at work, and you have also copy of full repository (called clone) at your home computer.  You can work at your home computer, comitting changes, reading commit messages, viewing differences, switching branches etc. without need to have constant network access to your computer at work.

Your question then is about how to **synchronize** repositories at work and at home.  There are many possibilities:

- You can create bare repostory (i.e. without working directory), clone of repository, on some removable media like USB disk (pendrive). You would sync via this repository, pushing to it from one place, and fetching (pulling) from it in other place.
- You can use one of [Git hosting services](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitHosting) like mentioned [GitHub](http://github.com), and use it to synchronize your repositories.  You should remember however that *usually* free plans require to make your repository public; if you want to have private repository you have to use paid plan (paid service). Check what the site you want to use is offering.
- You can use [git-bundle](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bundle.html) command:  generate bundle on one side using "git bundle" command, then clone/fetch/pull on the other side using bundle file in place of repository URL e.g. `git fetch file.bndl`. You can transfer bundle in any way, be it on USB flash drive, downloading it via HTTP (plain web server would be enough here), FTP or SCP.
- You can serve your repository via SSH. For that you need git to have installed both at work and on your home computer, ssh daemon on server (side you are fetching from / pushing to) and ssh client on client. Git doesn't need to be installed globally for all users on server; you can tell git where to find appropriate git binaries via relevant option (see git documentation). In [Tips and Tricks page on Git Wiki](http://git.or.cz/gitwiki/GitTips) you would find "How to push/pull via ssh to host behind gateway?" tip.
- Finally you can serve your repository via HTTP, using simple web server, just like you would publish web pages. You need to remember to run `git update-server-info` to generate helper information. Usually it is done from `post-update` hook (and `post-commit` if repository is non-bare, i.e. if you create commits in it); check out sample hook (and read [githooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) documentation) to see how it is done.

***See also*** my answer in [How can I make my local Git repository available for git-pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978052/githow-can-i-make-my-local-repository-available-for-git-pull/978417#978417) SO question.

Answer (score 2):

I love DropBox for this.  www.getdropbox.com

Comment: Dan are you actually using dropbox to synchronize two git repositories?  I can't believe that this would work if there are changes in repositories on both your home and work machines.  This solution seems like it is destined to corrupt your repository.

Comment: No, not to synchronize two git repositories.  I'm synchronizing one repository across multiple machines.

Comment: Same here, I got a bare repository in my Dropbox. Works fine. Then again I am the only one accessing it...

Comment: We had bad experiences using DropBox as a centralized location for git repository. After several time corruptions had happened, we realized that was due to the concurrent pushes from different users which couldn't handled by Dropbox.  Anyway, I think for personal use DropBox is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

Since GIT is decentralized, you have a complete copy of your repository on each system.  This leaves you flexibility to adopt a workflow for synchronizing your repositories that works for you.  Given what you said in your question I would recommend one of two options.

### Synchronize your Home and Work repositories via ssh

If your home machine and work machines are both accessible from the internet, then you can just ssh from one to the other and push pull changes to each local repository.  So:

1. SSH to your *other* machine (other being either work or home)
2. Pull down any remote repository changes
3. Push up any local repository changes.

### Synchronize your Home and Work repositories via central repository

This involves syncing both your work and home repository changes with a third repository location, which can be either on a hosted service like [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) or [GitHub](http://www.github.com), or any web-hosting service that gives you ssh access.

I prefer the second approach because it gives you a third copy of repository at yet another offsite location.

Answer (score 1):

Git is similar to subversion/sourcesafe, but it's design to be distributed.  You could make one act as a centralized server, or you could just work between your peers.  There's a few more model you could use, see mmc's links for more info.

GitHub is available on the web, but I suspect you want something hosted at work and no open to the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:
LogMeIn (https://secure.logmein.com/home.asp?lang=en)

for any other remote desktop access software.

See this for more such softwares -> http://mashable.com/2007/09/07/remote-access/

Answer (score 0):

Even though a central server may make things somewhat easier, you don't need one.

At work, I use some scripts around `git-bundle` to synchronize my git repositories between machines that are not connected to networks in a way that they can access each other. For moving around the bundles, I use either e-mail or USB thumb drives. (The machines in question couldn't even access a common third machine via IP connections).