# Do i need GIT Server for centralized/mirror to get GIT works?

Tags: git

I have worked with SVN using VisualSVN & TortoiseSVN for few years, and it works well for my 10 person department.

Git is very hot today, and I am considering whether or not to move from SVN to Git.

I read many posts on StackOverflow and I have a concept on git which

Git is decentralized & distributed VCS. Users can commit their revision on their local repositories whether the network connection is available or not.

Reference from this posts:
[Do I need a server to use git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173101/do-i-need-a-server-to-use-git)

To get it to work for multiple users, I still need a central Git server with **bare** repositories only to synchronise and let multiple users sync the files (like SVN - `update` command) or new users to own the files (like SVN - `checkout` command).

But my questions are:

1. Do I really need a server/web space being a bare repo for sync/mirror for general Git work flow?
2. What system requirement for GIT server? (like SVN have to use Apache)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, and there is no *general git workflow*. Read [this](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows) for examples of distributed worflows.
2. You only need a computer accepting connections through `ssh`, and `git` of course

A useful tool for managing this is [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite).

Comment: I'd go with @simon in this. You don't really need a _central_ dedicated server, considering the number of developers you have. If the number of developers are getting increased you might need it, just to stop loading your CPU. But in case you are a guy who tries out something new and crash your PC often, I strongly recommend a dedicated server for managing repositories.

Answer (score 1):

A Git server is to share repositories among many people.
In your case, you have a team of 10, so you need to setup one to share.
Team members may push their work when they think that they are ready to share.

You may use apache
in httpd.conf, add

```
SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT /path-to-git-repo-root
SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
ScriptAlias /url-path-to-git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/
```

Your url:

```
git clone http://server/url-path-to-git/xxx.git
```