# Git & SSH - pull from a local repo when logged in to Production server via SSH

Tags: git, production, repository

My code repo is in a bare directory on a local workstation.  I want to PULL from this repo from my production server while I am logged in to my production server via SSH.

`Production server => PULL from local workstation repo`

How would I do this?

There are [Five Ways to set up a repository to PULL from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978052/githow-can-i-make-my-local-repository-available-for-git-pull).  Seems SSH & Git protocols are my only options but I am stuck.  I can connect to the production server from my local workstation via SSH but how do I do the opposite?

EDIT:  Simply, how do I add the local workstation as a remote repo on the production server?

**ANSWER** Just for anyone else that may have a similar question.  You can follow the accepted answer below.  OR you can change the initial set up.  Change the repository from a local repository to a remote private repository in the cloud.  It makes it much easier as only SSH is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit backwards. You should be pushing to the repo first. Then log in and do what you need with the new version. You can't pull to a bare repo. It does not have a worktree. Pull is fetch and merge or rebase combined. The latter requires a worktree to accomplish.

If you are doing some work on the server, you can set up a non-bare repo on that remote machine next to the bare one and do any manipulation there.

Comment: Thanks Adam but perhaps I wasn't clear.  The bare repo is stored on a local (network) workstation.  Developers develop on their workstations and then push to the local bare repo.  On the production server, we would like to PULL from the bare repo.  Is that possible?  Or does our bare repo require cloud hosting (github, bitbucket, our own, etc.)?

Comment: You can have a non-bare repo on production that pulls from the bare repo where everyone pushes to.

Comment: To be sure I understand... move the local bare repo from the local network to the production server.  PUSH there as normal.  I am worried about that server being shut down and lost.

Comment: no.. don't move anything.. keep the bare repo where it is and continue to have the developers push to it. Make a new non-bare repo on production. Add a remote that points to the bare one. Pull using that remote on this new repo.

Comment: Thanks again.  That is exactly my original question.  HOW do I point to the bare repo since it can't be accessed via http?

Comment: You should set up a secure channel - VPN, for instance. I'm assuming you own the production servers. Or you host with some company?