# Git Server type repository in Local Windiws which can be forked

Tags: windows, git, version-control, tortoisegit

I am new to git...

I have a local project that i need to share with my friends and i want to work on it in the similar way that we work on Github.com

I want that the local repsoitory be exposed in the local network, and the GIT URL is shared with my friends directly as we do in the online version.

then they can fork my repo as per need and when they are done, they send pull requests and i can review and merge the same.

can i do this in windows at all and if yes..then please suggest how..

> **i have searched but only found ways to create local repo and not how**
>   **to expose the same. AND how to fork it..**

Please help..

PS i have tortoise git installed on my system

Comment: The following thread should help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/978417/2279816

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[Git\]How can I make my local repository available for git-pull?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978052/githow-can-i-make-my-local-repository-available-for-git-pull)

Comment: That still doesnt explain how will my friends fork the repository...

Answer (score 1):

You can consider **[GitBlit](http://gitblit.com/)** which has in [its features](http://gitblit.com/features.html):

> - Optional feature to fork a repository to a personal repository
> - Optional Issue Tracker and Pull-Request-like mechanism

It is a repository hosting service, so it can expose Git repos to other collaborators as well.

It is a bit different from the traditional pull-request workflow though: [see FAQ](http://gitblit.com/tickets_overview.html#H5)

> Gitblit uses a 3-repository workflow. This means that Gitblit cuts the fork repository out of the collaboration workflow: patchsets are pushed directly to a special branch of the canonical repository, not to a fork. You may also push to fork, if you want, but all collaboration occurs in the canonical repository, not your fork.

Comment: Will this work with my current repo style...???

i mean 1 git repo hosted on my system or some other system via git and instead of my cloning the repo, can i fork it...i dont want to host the repo at some other system...

Comment: @VineetVerma yes, you can clone a repo exposed with GitBLit (which can host your repo directly on your system).