# Standalone Git Daemon Creation

Tags: git

I want to create a standalone git server which could be used by git with `git://` urls.

I don't know where to start. LibGit2 does not seem to contain libraries for the daemon, only for clients. I could try to compile git and check the daemon but, if possible, I want to avoid that until I have no other option.

Where do I find a protocol description?

Comment: Have you Tried the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/978052/how-can-i-make-my-local-repository-available-for-git-pull    
http://review.cyanogenmod.org/Documentation/install.html

Answer (score 3):

The description of that protocol supported by git daemon is in [`git/git/Documentation/git-daemon.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/Documentation/git-daemon.txt).
That documentation also [include how to use it](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/Documentation/howto/use-git-daemon.txt).

> let's see an example:

```
$ git daemon --reuseaddr --verbose --base-path=/home/gitte/git \
  --export-all -- /home/gitte/git/rule-the-world.git
```

> (Of course, unless your user name is `gitte` *and* your repository is in
>   `~/rule-the-world.git`, you have to adjust the paths. If your repository is
>   not bare, be aware that you have to type the path to the `.git` directory!)

See also [Git on the Server - Git Daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon) and [git:// protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol).

For even more details, see this [exercise reimplementing the git protocol](http://stefan.saasen.me/articles/git-clone-in-haskell-from-the-bottom-up/):

[image: http://stefan.saasen.me/articles/git-clone-in-haskell-from-the-bottom-up/images/git-clone-overview@2x.png]

[image: http://stefan.saasen.me/articles/git-clone-in-haskell-from-the-bottom-up/images/pack-client-server.png]

That new implementation is in Haskell, but can give you an idea of the steps to follow in order to implement your own in your own language.

Comment: I am looking to create a new standalone daemon, not to learn how to use the existing one.

Comment: Although the stuff there is useful, it mainly describes a clone client, not a server.