# Git push error: RPC failed: curl 52

Tags: git, ubuntu

git push fails with following error

```
fatal: RPC failed: curl 52: Empty reply from server
```

The upload succeeds in case only one file was modified, added or deleted.

The following settings to don't work reliably

```
 git config --global --add core.compression -1
```

The git version is 2.8.2 running on ubuntu 14.04, and I have tried with both openssl and gnutls compilations.

ssh remotes also fail.

The problem is encountered with repositories of

```
bitbucket
github
gitlab
```

Fail safe answers appreciated

Comment: Do any commands to the server work?  Can you do `git push` ?

Comment: git push works fine only for modification of a single file.

Comment: This problem appears to have many causes, including the server going down or using an old version of Git.

Comment: <status.bitbucket.org/> says 'via https' is operational, and 2.8.2 is latest available stable git version

Comment: Same here and it looks like it's doing it only on certain repos, I have 6 repos on bitbucket it's only doing it on one of them. Everything up to date. Support ticket sent but still not heard back.

Comment: Have you got its solution?

Comment: @sulimo has you solved it yet?

Answer (score 17):

In terminal use sudo to clone, or type:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400
```

its worked for me

Comment: Worked for me as well on Mac OS X on repo on BitBucket

Comment: using sudo to clone did not fix this for me

Comment: This worked for me also. Any idea *what* makes it happen and *why* this fix works?

Answer (score 16):

Following worked for me.

```
git config --global core.compression 0

git clone --depth 1 <repo> //  partial clone to truncate the amount of info coming down

#cd repo // go into the new directory and 

git fetch --unshallow //retrieve the rest of the clone

git pull --all //final pull
```

Hope, this could be helpful for someone having the same issue.

Comment: YOU SAVED MY REPOS!

Comment: `git config --global core.compression 0` solved saved my repo.

Comment: Looks like it helps when remote hungs up due to something blocking too big requests. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I had a chat with Gideon @ atlassian he suggested to use SSH over HTTPS to fix the "curl 52" error.

For me switching to SSH fixed the problem. Here's the complete answer:

> This is a HTTP/HTTPS timeout issue involving either some large commit
> size, or a weak network. If you're cloning, can you try to see if you
> can clone the repository using this method:
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22317479
>
> Can you try to see if running this
> command before any git operations help as well:
>
> `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`
>
> Also, this issue usually won't occur in SSH;
> so maybe it is worth trying to set up SSH and then do the operation
> through SSH:
>
> https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html

Comment: Thanks, it works. I found the way to switch to SSH at: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me.
stop  WIFI and use the Network cable to connect the NetWork

Maybe it is a problem about network

Comment: I had the same issue. Your statement about the problem with the network was right. But I had vice-versa: I stopped LAN connection and started Wi-Fi, it resolved the issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem on arch linux, git version 2.8.2, can't push to bitbucket repo.
Cloning and pull works.

Comment: @Dado: Sorry for commenting here, I can't comment your answer yet. I tried earlier with changing postBuffer size, but it didn't work, I have a good internet connection and, and I modified only 4 not too big files (few hundred lines c++ code ~50 lines changed all in all). I nevertheless tried ssh, but it also fails with: `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Comment: Interesting I had problems pulling instead ;) Try to open a ticket with them they are quite good with customer service. (the only thing I can think of is just make sure that you aren't accidentally still using HTTPS)

Answer (score 0):

Appearently it's a problem with HTTPS problem. 
Switching to SSH fix the problem with all repositories.

Answer (score 0):

This happened in my case during a push and it was seemingly due to duplicate consecutive commit messages.  Once I amended (git commit --amend) the second message to be slightly different from the first, pushed again, and success.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but for pull and fetch.
Fetching or pulling from anywhere (Visual Studio, command line, etc) was failing with this error.
Re-cloning the repository using the "Git GUI" for Windows was failing with the same error too.

For whatever reason, re-cloning the repository from the command line worked (either due to luck or due to some different git version being used between the two?) and I got a new working local repository.

I have fetched/pulled from the new local repository to the old (using the first method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/978417/2173353)), in order to minimize the things the old repo had to pull from the remote in order to get in sync, but it was still failing after the update. So, this appeared to be something with the repository, not with HTTP for me...

I could not try with SSH to see if there was any difference.