# setup git repo locally for different people without giving my password

Tags: git

I want to setup a git repo in one of my cloud instance to share with a few people.
Currently I've set it in /home/my_home_dir/git_dir. However, it always ask for my password when my teammates want to clone from it. Is there any way to set it up without giving away my password or private key?

Thanks...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my local repository available for git-pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978052/how-can-i-make-my-local-repository-available-for-git-pull)

Comment: http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/