# How to allow another user to pull from the origin in GIT

Tags: git

As I am still learning `git`, i stumbled upon a question. We have a team, where are multiple repos and two users. First I was the only one and in my production server I had config, with my `remote origin`. I can pull changes over SSH just fine.

Since another member joined the team, he needs to be able to pull the changes as well, if I am on vacation for example. Under the config I only see my username and `use` my own email.

Can I add another developer to the list somehow for him to be able to pull the changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make my local repository available for git-pull?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978052/how-can-i-make-my-local-repository-available-for-git-pull)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a user in your *git* server that your company use.

That will create an account with credentials your colleague can use to log in and pull data with *git*